# Adding Controls inside a GridView Dynamically Asp.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am  using ASP.Net Gridview Control. It has 3 columns. The First two Columns are dropdowns and the third column is generated based  on the selection of second column. I am adding control inside the third column dynamically. Below is my code:

```
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Text = "Text Box Added";
Gridview1.Rows[currentRow.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls.Add(txtBox);
```

I have taken a template field and an empty item template in my third column. My both the dropdowns are also inside an item template which are inside their respective update panels. They have their AutoPostBack ="True". Now when i select the first dropdown, the second dropdown gets filled and when i select the second the control gets added in the third dropdown. But now when i go to  the next row and do the same activity, the controls which were added dynamically previously gets removed. Please help me. I have used UpdateMode as Conditional too. Still i am getting this issue. Why my previous controls gets removed.?

Comment: Are you sure you need the server to be involved? Seems like this is a perfect case for JavaScript and a textbox example of trying to do too much on the server, and a strong case against update panels and adding controls dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Mason for your reply. :) And Yes the requirenent is for doing in postbacks. Currently i did with update panels. Now i am getting one issue i.e how can i get the vaue of the dynamicallly created textbox inside gridview.?